# Where do Mathematica's probability functions draw a line in the sand for predicates?

Tags: evaluation, probability-or-statistics

Thinking about a recent question mis-posted here (belonged on *math*), I noted the following.

A contrived example - probability that *a* or *b* are 1:

```
Probability[ a == 1 || b == 1, {a \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}],
  b \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}]
```

outputs as expected 3/4. Now if one had a more complicated predicate, say ten variates involved, it would be a messy predicate to do manually. Of course, one could use various facilities to build it auto-magically, or just use something like (keeping it simple as above, but one can see how this makes extension to many variates simple):

```
Probability[Total[Unitize[{a, b}]] > 0, {a \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}],
  b \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}]
```

which returns the expected result.

However, something that intuitively seems it *should* work, like:

```
Probability[
 Count[{a, b}, 0] != 2, {a \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}],
  b \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}]
```

does not, and somewhat worryingly returns a result (invalid) of 1 rather than an error or warning for an unusable predicate.

The same results occur with `NProbability`.

(1) Is there any rhyme or reason around what works and what doesn't?

(2) Is there any method to get *Mathematica* to use such a construct directly, or at least spit back a "no can do"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case there's an easy explanation:

`Count[{a, b}, 0]` immediately evaluates to 0, so we end up with `Probability[ 0 != 2, ...]`, then `Probability[True, ...]`, which is 1.

To be able to give a warning, `Probability` would need to be `HoldAll` and check the arguments before they're evaluated.

I do think that this is a somewhat tricky point, but the problem runs deeper than `Probability` and has to do with how the language is designed.  A less rigid language structure gives more room for making uncatchable mistakes.

---

The following does seems to work:

```
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Count[{a, b}, 0] != 2

Probability[
 f[a, b], {a \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}], b \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}]
```

Actually I'm a bit surprised to find that blackbox functions do work with `Probability`.  It probably builds a complete probability table to be able to do this.

Comment: ... where `?NumericQ` is the secret sauce!

Comment: +1 well done, I'd tried that but *without* the "secret sauce". N.B.: It appears it is sufficient to just have that on any one of the arguments.